# Plant care and identification

Tags: identification, plant-care

I just received a flower, but I really don't know how to keep it alive as long as possible. I'm assuming that it's not going to stay alive forever as it's not potted, but is just keeping it in water enough?

As an extra, if you happen to know, I would like to know what flower this is. It was referred as "The most pixelated flower we could find." ;)

Thanks for your time!

[image: Uknown flower]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are stems cut from one of the Leucadendron laureolum hybrids; they are sold by florists usually in autumn/early winter in the northern hemisphere. The plants are shrubs in the Protea family that grow in warmer parts of the world - they do not tolerate much cold, some detail here https://www.burncoose.co.uk/site/plants.cfm?pl_id=5862. There are many shades of foliage with these plants, but the one you usually buy as a cut stem is similar to 'Burgundy Sunset'.

As cut stems, they will last in water for quite some time - I've had them for up to 8 weeks, because they tend to dry out rather than flop and shrivel. Just change the water every 2 or 3 days, as you would with any bunch of cut flowers. They are usually displayed with other flowers for contrast, but Leucadendron stems will outlast ordinary cut flowers such as roses or  chrysanthemums.

Comment: Awesome info! Thank you very much :)